# Delete all descendants of an entry (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with, let's say, the following columns:

`Name` ,  `Parent Name`,   `ID`

Let's also say that there are three entries where Parent Name is Null (meaning they are the top-most parent) - F_one, G_one, and H_one.

If I want to delete all the descendants of one of those parents (G_one, why not?) meaning all the children of G_one, all the children of those children, and the children of those, and so on all the way until the terminal level where, that row's `Name` does not exist as a `Parent Name` for any other entry.

Is that possible to be done easily, maybe with a single query?

Bonus, is there a way to select all of the G_one lineage so I can manipulate it to my whim and will?

Can assume: 
-No Children are shared among parents

Cannot assume:
-A discrete or even consistent number of sub-levels.

Comment: Do you have an explicit foreign key relationship for this? Deleting a parent record would normally cascade the delete to all child records. If not, then you'll have to use a loop and work your way down the tree, deleting each level as you find it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with foreign keys. Can it be used for this, within a single table? As far as looping, I'm trying to avoid that because I would have to, for example, store all the children of G_one, then delete G_one, then select all grandchildren of G_one and store those, then delete the children, and so on...right?

Comment: Is the table using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marc B's suggestion, a `FORIEGN KEY` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` would achieve this.

If you haven't one, you can add it now:

1. If there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `Name` (I assume the `PRIMARY` key os `ID`), skip thi sstep. If there ism't one, create it:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tableX
     ADD CONSTRAINT unique_Name
       UNIQUE (Name) ;
   ```
2. If the previous step succeeded, add the `FOREIGN KEY`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tableX
     ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Name_ParentName
       FOREIGN KEY (ParentName)
          REFERENCES tableX (Name)
          ON UPDATE CASCADE
          ON DELETE CASCADE ;
   ```
3. If the previous step succeeded, you can now delete your rows with one statement:

   ```
   DELETE
   FROM tableX
   WHERE ParentName = 'G_one' ;
   ```

   This should result in: `Y rows affected`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but I think something like this might work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER casc_del AFTER DELETE on tblName
FOR EACH ROW 
    DELETE FROM tblName 
    WHERE tblName.parent_name is not null 
    AND tblName.parent_name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM tblName)
```

More about triggers in MySQL can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Note: this approach would only work in 5.02 or later.